# Weird character when writing to file

Tags: c

This is the code I have written to split the file into parts. The language in the code is irrelevant, I'll show you the relevant part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

long meret(FILE* fajl) {

    long jelenlegi = ftell(fajl);
    long meret;

    fseek(fajl, 0L, SEEK_END);

    meret = ftell(fajl);

    fseek(fajl, jelenlegi, SEEK_SET);

    return meret;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp, *fptemp;
    long size, tmpsize;
    int db;
    int ct = 1, i = 0, index = 0, j, z;
    char temp[30];
    char temp2[30];
    char actual[30];
    char filenev[30];
    char s[60];
    char *tmp;
    char filenevsorsz[5];
    char *aktualis, ment[30];

    printf("A hasznalat: \n");
    printf("------------\n\n");
    printf("Elso parancssori argumentum: -d\n");
    printf("Masodik: a file elerhetosege\n");
    printf("Harmadik: darabolasban a darabok maximalis merete byte-ban!\n\n");

    if(argc != 4) {

        printf("Nem jo a hasznalat! Olvasd el a hasznalati utmutatot!");
        return;

    }

    fp = fopen(argv[2], "rt");

    if(!fp) {

        printf("Hiba a file megnyitasakor...");
        return;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    size = meret(fp);
    printf("A file merete: %d byte\n", size);
    printf("A megadott darabolasi parameter: %s\n\n", argv[3]);
    db = atoi(argv[3]);
    printf("Osszesen %d file-ra kell szamitanunk.\n", (size/30)+1);
    j = 0;

    for(i=0; i<strlen(argv[2])-4; i++) {

        filenev[j++] = argv[2][i];

    }

    tmp = malloc(sizeof(filenev));
    strcpy(tmp,filenev);
    aktualis = malloc(sizeof(db));
    i = 1;

    while(i<=3) {
        printf("Most csinalom a %d. fajlt...", i);
        strcpy(filenev, tmp);
        fread(aktualis, 1, db, fp);
        printf(" Az aktualis sor: %s\n", aktualis);
        strcat(filenev, "00");
        sprintf(filenevsorsz, "%d", i);
        strcat(filenev, filenevsorsz);
        strcat(filenev, ".txt");
        fptemp = fopen(filenev, "a");
        fprintf(fptemp, "%s", aktualis);
        printf("A filenev: %s", filenev);
        tmpsize = meret(fptemp);
        printf("\nA meret: %ld byte\n", tmpsize);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }


}
```

What this does: it reads a file, it reads X bytes (command line arg) from the file, and creates sub files from it.

For example: test.txt contains 30 bytes. If I set to split by 10 bytes each, it will give me: 
test001.txt
test002.txt
test003.txt

This is the relevant part:

```
while(i<=3) {
        printf("Most csinalom a %d. fajlt...", i);
        strcpy(filenev, tmp);
        fread(aktualis, 1, db, fp);
        printf(" Az aktualis sor: %s\n", aktualis);
        strcat(filenev, "00");
        sprintf(filenevsorsz, "%d", i);
        strcat(filenev, filenevsorsz);
        strcat(filenev, ".txt");
        fptemp = fopen(filenev, "a");
        fprintf(fptemp, "%s", aktualis);
        printf("A filenev: %s", filenev);
        tmpsize = meret(fptemp);
        printf("\nA meret: %ld byte\n", tmpsize);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
```

It copies to all file fine (into 10 bytes each) EXCEPT the first one. It will give me some weird characters and the whole file will be 4 bytes shorter with every single file I tried. But whenever I try to print the read line (30 byte) it will print it fine, EXCEPT when printing it to file, it gives me this random character. Any suggestions?

Comment: I see you've allocated 30 character buffers for your 30 byte files and processing them as strings... did you leave enough room for the null terminator?

Comment: `aktualis = malloc(sizeof(db));` should probably be `aktualis = malloc(db);` ?

Comment: In addition to above comments: `fread(aktualis, 1, db, fp); printf(" Az aktualis sor: %s\n", aktualis); fprintf(fptemp, "%s", aktualis);`. The data in `aktualis` is not a C string. Reading from a text file with `fread` will never produce a C string (unless you explicitly NUL terminate the buffer after reading). You cannot treat it as such.

Comment: Bloody hell mate.. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Splitting on bytes vs characters (utf8 codepoints). The language in the code looks like Hungarian, which has some characters that are not a single byte but are multibyte utf8 sequences (i.e. a character can be 1-4 bytes). If the data in the file is the same, a raw split on a given number of bytes might split a utf8 sequence in the middle and you have fileN ending with a garbage/wrong sequence and fileN+1 starting with the same. Consider your own name. It is utf8: Instead of `Gabor` (5 bytes), it is `G<C3><A1>bor` (6 bytes). Try splitting it on two _bytes_ ;-)

Comment: This is a new spin on Hungarian notation.

Comment: `strcpy(tmp,filenev);` may invoke *undefined behavior*. Do not forget to null-terminate "strings" before passing it to string-manipuration functions such as `strcpy()`.

Comment: when calling `fread()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.   Some of those 'magic' numbers are 60, 30, 5, 3. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the posted code opens several files, but fails to call `fclose()` for each of those files, before exiting.

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: When there is the error that the command line did not contain the correct number of parameters.  1) output the error message to `stderr` using `fprint( stderr, ....)`  and the format string should be a USAGE statement, similar to: `"USAGE: %s <parm1> <parm2> <parm3>\n"` followed by the parameter: `argv[0] );`

Comment: when outputting a error message, driven by the returned value from a call to a system function, 1) output the error message to `stderr` 2) include the system error message, similar to: `perror( "fopen for input file failed" );`

Comment: these lines: ` for(i=0; i<strlen(argv[2])-4; i++) {

        filenev[j++] = argv[2][i];

    }` can be replaced with: `strcpy( filenev, argv[2] );`